# How to have a radio button and a text field on the same line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have a radio button and a text field on the same line. I want the text box to take the remaining width. I have tried to float the elements etc. but then the radio button is not vertically aligned with the text input any longer. What do I need to do? This is my current HTML, where the text field does not take the entire width remaining.

```
<li>
    <input type="radio"
           name="answers"
           value="true" />

        <input type="text" />
</li>
```

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle of your current efforts.

Comment: Within an `li` element they will be on the same line anyway http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/fpUk7/

Comment: @Vector Yes, but I said the text field should take the entire width...

Comment: Without some context there is no possible way to answer your question.  Depending on the applied style and the surrounding html this can display in almost an infinite amount of ways...

Answer (score 0):

Consider applying some CSS to the elements.

```css
input[type=radio],
input[type=text] {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type=radio] {
    width: 10%;
}
input[type=text] {
    width: 89%;
}
```